# How to wait for a video background in HTML until it finish and then view the contents of body section?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I have a video that I'm setting as background in my HTML code:

```
<video id="video" autoplay loop poster="poster.jpg" muted>
<source src="vid-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="vid-bg.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The CSS For It:

#container {

```
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 0.6;
```

}

The JS function I' m using to set the background and also to reset it when user resize the window:

```
$(function() {


// IE detect
function iedetect(v) {

    var r = RegExp('msie' + (!isNaN(v) ? ('\\s' + v) : ''), 'i');
    return r.test(navigator.userAgent);

}

// For mobile screens, just show an image called 'poster.jpg'. Mobile
// screens don't support autoplaying videos, or for IE.
if(screen.width < 800 || iedetect(8) || iedetect(7) || 'ontouchstart' in window) {

    (adjSize = function() { // Create function called adjSize

        $width = $(window).width(); // Width of the screen
        $height = $(window).height(); // Height of the screen

        // Resize image accordingly
        $('#container').css({
            'background-image' : 'url(poster.jpg)', 
            'background-size' : 'cover', 
            'width' : $width+'px', 
            'height' : $height+'px'
        });

        // Hide video
        $('video').hide();

    })(); // Run instantly

    // Run on resize too
    $(window).resize(adjSize);
}
else {


    // Wait until the video meta data has loaded
    $('#container video').on('loadedmetadata', function() {

          // for debugging          
        //alert('we are here');

        var $width, $height, // Width and height of screen
            $vidwidth = this.videoWidth, // Width of video (actual width)
            $vidheight = this.videoHeight, // Height of video (actual height)
            $aspectRatio = $vidwidth / $vidheight; // The ratio the video's height and width are in

        (adjSize = function() { // Create function called adjSize

            $width = $(window).width(); // Width of the screen
            $height = $(window).height(); // Height of the screen

            $boxRatio = $width / $height; // The ratio the screen is in

            $adjRatio = $aspectRatio / $boxRatio; // The ratio of the video divided by the screen size

            // Set the container to be the width and height of the screen
            $('#container').css({'width' : $width+'px', 'height' : $height+'px'}); 

            if($boxRatio < $aspectRatio) { // If the screen ratio is less than the aspect ratio..
                // Set the width of the video to the screen size multiplied by $adjRatio
                $vid = $('#container video').css({'width' : $width*$adjRatio+'px'}); 
            } else {
                // Else just set the video to the width of the screen/container
                $vid = $('#container video').css({'width' : $width+'px'});
            }

        })(); // Run function immediately

        // Run function also on window resize.
        $(window).resize(adjSize);

    });
}
```

});

The problem that i have is when i click refresh in my web browser the video doesn't get loaded and i get the poster of the video which i have in my computer, how can i bypass the problem?
I was thinking to set a timeout delay, hide the body contents and check it in a for loop until the `$("video").readState() === 4` and then show the contents of the body, but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you know about events ? MediaElement have [a bunch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding onplay event to the video and call your js function to display the body when the video starts and by default set body display to none:

```
//By default  loading animation will show and in onPlay hide that animation
<body  onload="vidLoading()">
    <script>
    function onPlay()
    {
        $('.bodyWrapper').css("display","block"); //show the body of the html page
        $('.animationDiv').css("display":"none");
    }
    </script>
    <div class="bodyWrapper" style="display:none">
        <video id="video" autoplay loop poster="poster.jpg" muted onplay="onPlay()">
        <source src="vid-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="vid-bg.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="animationDiv">Animation Div</div>

</body>
```

Comment: It didn't work, i tried to look on the requests sent, i found it was not showing the video file, but when i wait for some 40 seconds click on refresh on the web browser the video will autoplay and work as background.

Comment: I have edited my answer show some animation on body load and video must be taking longer to load thats why nothing is visible till that point

Comment: I noticed the response that I'm getting from the server is HTTP 206 Partial Content.

Comment: yeah video gets load with that response usually how long is the video ?

Comment: Yes exactly that's why it's not visible it takes longer to load.

Comment: The video is 1080p high resolution video, the length of the video is 12s, and the size of the file is 4mb with a type of mp4.

Comment: I think your best bet is to show animation and then hide it in onPlay fn as I suggested in my answer ...When you refresh the page its lot faster because the content is cached at that stage

Comment: So if I'm going to hide body how i suppose to show the animation for the user?

Comment: So inside my vidLoading() func i should have something like this to show the animation:
`$("animationDiv").fadeIn(2000);`
right?

Comment: You can have any html in that div and you don't need to show it in vidLoading fn as it by default visible

Comment: is it visible before video loading or after?

Comment: it will get hide after the video loads and display the body container mate

Comment: Thanks for helping me, your code looks fine, it's just my browser settings it had to change, i have answered my question below, look at it for any more details.